# Regular expression to match one rule OR another

Tags: regex

In a Joomla module, I'm using regular expressions to show a module in pages that contain:

```
/comprar-curso/
```

And trying to hide it from pages:

```
/comprar-curso/produto/83-acesso-a-todos-os-cursos-180-dias.html
/comprar-curso/produto/84-acesso-a-todos-os-cursos-365-dias.html
```

These are the lines with the Regex I'm using:

```
\/comprar-curso\/produto\/?(?!\/?83-acesso-a-todos-os-cursos-180-dias.html)
\/comprar-curso\/produto\/?(?!\/?84-acesso-a-todos-os-cursos-365-dias.html)
```

However, it seems each line is defining a rule, so the 2 lines together represent an `AND` condition.

I need one Regex line to hide from one page `OR` another.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there no mechanism for *excluding* patterns?

Comment: Maybe there's a way to do that, good idea!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want is this:

```
\/comprar-curso\/produto\/8(?:3(?=.+180)|4(?=.+365))-acesso-a-todos-os-cursos-(?:180|365)-dias\.html
```

It uses a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and an alternation to ensure that the two pages are matched with the correct second number.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GcUZBe/1)

Comment: Thanks, but that expression is also hiding the module in the pages it should be displayed, like: /comprar-curso/produto/82-curso-fiscalidade-angolana.html

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It doesn't match that URL ([demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GcUZBe/2))